# Acessar valor indice de um array

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como faço pra pegar o valor do indice do array em cada interação, sem precisar de colocar a possição exemplo PermissionUsuarioFilter.UserPermissionId[0] preciso do indice dinamico e não estatico.
[image: console]
Preciso que a classe fique dessa forma
[image: classe]

Comment: Será que não era para você estar fazendo `permissionSalve.PermissionId = item;` ?

Comment: Justamente, mas agora ele só esta salvando o ultimo item da lista no banco.

Comment: não vi o código todo mas, não entendo o pq desse `Deserialize`, se passar o parametro corretamente do javascript não precisa disseo, o método deveria aceitar `List<long>` como parametro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No método `.each(` é posivel pegar a posição do array `index` e valor que ele contem `value`.

```
.each( function (index,value)
```

Na primeira interação `index` igual `0` e `value` igual `{UserPermissionId : 7}`

Assim você pode dar um `value.UserPermissionId` para obter o valor `7`

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte.

Comment: não da porque são dois arrays, um UserPermission e outro PermissionUsuario, quero comprar os valores identicos dos dois e marchar o "checked",true para os valores ==, o each não aceita dois arrays como parametro.

Comment: Ok, use o outro `.each()` para pode percorrer a lista filtrada, assim você poderá obter o resultado que deseja.